# Prove a property of an antichain.

Tags: combinatorics

A family of subsets $F$ of $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ is called an antichain if there is no pair of sets $A \in F$ and $B \in F$ satisfying $A \subset B$.

Let $f_k$ be the number of sets in $F$ with size $k$. Show that

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{f_k}{\binom nk} \le 1$$

**Hint from the book**

Choose a random permutation of the numbers from $1$ to $n$, and let the random variable $X_k = 1$ if the first $k$ numbers in this permutation is in $F$. If $X = \sum_{k=0}^n X_k$, what can you say about $X$?

**My attempt**

Consider the permutation hinted by the book. For a given permutation, $X = \sum_{k=0}^n X_k \le 1$, since otherwise the two sets would violate the antichain condition. For a given set $S$ in $F$ with $k$ elements, there must exists $k! (n-k)!$ such permutations so that the first $k$ elements is equal to $S$. But this will only proof that $f_k / \binom nk \le 1$. I am lost on how to relate this to the sum over all $k$.

**Meta**

This is exercise 6.10b from the book "Probability and Computing". This exercise appears in a chapter describing the probabilistic method. This exercise has a continuation in 6.10c (which asks you to proof that $|F| \le \binom{n}{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}$ for any antichain $F$). Also, I am positive that part (a) is completely unrelated to part (b) (part (a) asks you to give an example of $F$ such that $|F| = \binom{n}{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor})$. I can do (a), and (given (b) is true) I can do (c). But, both without any probabilistic method, so I'm not sure if this exercise use the probabilistic method unless (b) is evil.

Comment: Just to mention, this is the **LYM inequality** (Lubell–Yamamoto–Meshalkin inequality) on Sperner families (aka antichains)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$E(X)=E(\sum_{k=0}^nX_k)=\sum_{k=0}^nE(X_k).$$Since the random variable $X_k$ takes only values $0$ and $1$,$$E(X_k)=\operatorname{Prob}(X_k=1)=\frac{f_k}{\binom nk}.$$
Hence$$\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{f_k}{\binom nk}=\sum_{k=0}^nE(X_k)=E(X)\le1.$$

Comment: ...this is quite a clever usage of expectation. Thank you!